# Centralizando informações

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia.
Estamos começando a desenvolver várias soluções pequenas para web (Utilizamos Laravel) para atender as necessidades de nossos cliente, com base nisso me surgiu uma grande questão. Gostaria de centralizar toda informação que será utilizada em todo os projetos para ficar em um lugar e cada aplicação com sua peculiaridade em outro, exemplo:
Tenho um módulo de documento fiscais e outro de pedido, gostaria de centralizar as informações de clientes em um só lugar para que tanto o módulo de pedido como o módulo de documentos fiscais acessem a mesma informação. Alguma sugestão de como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: Relacionamento de tabela, a tabela do cliente com os dados do cliente, e por exemplo a tabela de documentos fiscais, com um campo de identificação do id do cliente para relacionamento da tabela, assim você identifica qual documento fiscal é de qual cliente. Uma das soluções é esta, tem outros meios, dependendo de qual banco de dados você faz uso.

Comment: Você diz, utilizar o mesmo banco de dados para todas as aplicações  ?

Comment: Sim, porém criando relacionamento entre as tabelas, através de um campo que identifica o cliente, ou uma tabela a parte que que relaciona as tabelas, por exemplo, no documento fiscal um campo que armazena o ID do cliente, ou uma tabela cliente_documentos onde você tem um campo ID do documento e mais um campo ID do cliente.

Comment: Sim, desta forma já trabalho. O problema é que acho que o banco de dados vai ficando muito grande, pensei se teria outra forma de fazer isto pra que meu BD fique mais organizado. Imagine como ficaria um banco de dados para 10 aplicações diferentes  ? srsrs

Comment: e qual a dificuldade em trabalhar com banco de dados com grande volume de informação?

Comment: Digo pelo fato de organização, já trabalhou como esse tipo de situação ? Se sim não ve nenhum problema ?

Comment: Nenhum problema, trabalho com volume de dados onde um .SQL exportado chega a 200mb, outros menores, outros maiores, é apenas questão de uma boa estruturação do seu DB e o relacionamento de tabelas. Até mesmo para manutenção é mais fácil.

Comment: legal, @EliseuB. Muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Trabalhe com procedures, que também ajuda e muito no processo de performance e na manutenção do seu DB, e até levando em consideração que você ganha tempo. Abraço.

Comment: Poderia criar uma API que centralizava as informações das suas aplicações. A ideia iria funcionar mais ou menos como um banco compartilhado. E sua aplicação iria consumir os serviços da API (Responsável por fazer o cruzamento dos dados dos seus módulos etc).